# Handling DataIntegrityViolationExceptions in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Let's say I have Airport entity with attribute:

```
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private final String code;
```

Obviously, when I persist entity with code I used before, it would throw `DataIntegrityViolationException`

I have Spring Boot app with Spring Data REST enabled.

For such situations, there is`RepositoryRestExceptionHandler` to handle `DataIntegrityViolationException`s and map them to **409** status code:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ OptimisticLockingFailureException.class, DataIntegrityViolationException.class })
ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> handleConflict(Exception o_O) {
    return errorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, new HttpHeaders(), o_O);
}
```

Typical response would look like as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 409
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 10:21:31 GMT

{
  "cause" : {
    "cause" : {
      "cause" : null,
      "message" : "Unique index or primary key violation: \"UK_X9RMMVEVTW274QQXGT73OQ74_INDEX_C ON PUBLIC.AIRPORT(CODE) VALUES ('null', 54)\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into AIRPORT (id, rec_version, code, description) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23505-194]"
    },
    "message" : "could not execute statement"
  },
  "message" : "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"UK_X9RMMVEVTW274QQXGT73OQ74_INDEX_C ON PUBLIC.AIRPORT(CODE) VALUES ('null', 54)\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into AIRPORT (id, rec_version, code, description) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23505-194]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

The question is whether it is good approach to sprinkle responses with SQL exceptions. In my opinion it's not.

If not, what are good practices to follow and how to implement them in Boot and Data REST?

Comment: The correct solution is to apply your own validation before it gets to the database either via a Spring Validator implementation or via a Custom JSR303 annotation.

Comment: In this case the validation logic has to do db lookup to see whether Airport with given code already exists. Is it good approach? Performance wise?

Based on this comment, JSR303 is not recommended way to go: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6574#issuecomment-240699651

Comment: Well how else are you going to do it other than a database lookup. You cannot let it fail at DB commit time as that is not going to let you produce a **meaningful** error messages: no client will want to see your SQL exception.

Comment: I suggest that you return HTTP Status of LOCKED(423) with any DataIntegrityViolationException

Answer (score 4):

**Whether it is good approach to sprinkle responses with SQL exceptions?**

In most cases, it is preferred to convert such exceptions into a custom error-message/ error-code before send it to client-app.

**What are good practices to follow and how to implement them in Boot and Data REST?**

In spring-boot & REST, you can implement your own ExceptionController/ExceptionHandler for such type of exception hanlding. Here you can catch any type of exception, and can convert it any form of custom object.

For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class ExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception e) {
    UserResponse response = null;

    if(e instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException){
        DataIntegrityViolationException ex = (DataIntegrityViolationException) e;
        response = new UserResponse(ErrorCodes.DuplicateMobNo, "This mobile no is already Registered!");
        return new ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(response, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

Where UserResponse can be something like this:

```
public class UserResponse extends GenericResponse{

    private Long customErrorCode;
    private String errorMsg;

public UserResponse() {

}

    public UserResponse(Long code, String msg) {
        this.customErrorCode = code;
        this.errorMsg = msg;
    }

    public String getCustomErrorCode () {
        return customErrorCode ;
    }

    public void setCustomErrorCode (Long customErrorCode ) {
        this.customErrorCode = customErrorCode ;
    }

    public String getErrorMsg  () {
        return errorMsg ;
    }

    public void setErrorMsg  (String errorMsg ) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg ;
    }
}
```

You can create your own custom Error code like DuplicateMobileNo and so

Comment: How do you determine what field the error relates to?

Comment: This example is too specific and cannot be generally applied across all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> handleException(DataIntegrityViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    log.error("DataIntegrity Violation Exception ::: {}", ex);
    
    String message = ex.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();

    if (message != null) {
        message = message.split("for")[0];
    } else {
        message = ResponseCodeEnum.R_66.getRespDescription();
    }
    
    BaseResponse baseResponse = new BaseResponse();
    baseResponse.setResponseCode(ResponseCodeEnum.R_66.getRespCode());
    baseResponse.setResponseDescription(message);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(baseResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

This solution is not perfect but it extracts the main value causing the exception and you can return that back to the user. The thinking behind this is that at least they are able to know the exact value causing the issue and use then they know the value to change or adjust.