# How do I map Spring Data's DataIntegrityViolationException to a clear, specific response body message?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Suppose, my authentication server gets a sign-up request: "I'm John Doe, get me registered". If I have a `UNIQUE` constraint on my `username` column, I have two options

1. I can hit a database, check whether a "John Doe" already exists, and respond with a 409 if it does; otherwise, persist the new user, send a token. *Major drawback: an extra IO operation on each successful sign-up*
2. Alternatively, I can just try to persist a new user right away

Suppose, I choose the latter option. But here's a challenge: in case the constraint *is* violated, how do I know (and reflect that in the response body) what *exactly* went wrong? My exception stack is as follows:

1. `DataIntegrityViolationException` (Spring Data)
2. `ConstraintViolationException` (Hibernate)
3. `PSQLException` (Postgres)

`DataIntegrityViolationException` provides a message and a cause, nothing more. At this point, I don't know:

- *which's column's* constraint was violated (suppose there are more `UNIQUE` columns in the table, and they are represented in the DTO);
- or even *what constraint* was violated (could be some `NOT NULL`).

`DataIntegrityViolationException`'s message may look something like this:

> could not execute statement [ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "users_username_key"
> Подробности: Ключ "(username)=(John Doe)" уже существует.] [insert into users (enabled,password,username,id) values (?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into users (enabled,password,username,id) values (?,?,?,?)]; constraint [null]

I don't want to send it to the user as is because of all the irrelevant low-level details. I want to send back in my response body something like, "Username 'John Doe' is already taken. Pick another one". Short, to the point. Obviously, I don't want to [parse the message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029051/23434786)

The message is not generated by Spring, it's taken from `PSQLException`, the bottom of the stack. If I go *that* low, I may extract a `ServerErrorMessage` object...

```java
ServerErrorMessage serverErrorMessage = ((PSQLException) ((DataIntegrityViolationException) t).getRootCause())
                                                                                    .getServerErrorMessage();
```

...and then invoke `getConstraint()` on it. In my case, I got `users_username_key`. I figure it's Postgres's default name for `username`'s `UNIQUE` constraint. Once I have this, I can, in theory, provide a useful response message to the user

Major drawbacks:

- I couple my code with a low-level, RDBMS-specific type. *Bad*
- I can't send `users_username_key` as is too, it's still quite low-level (because of the word "key"). If I put some `if` (`if (c.equals("users_username_key")) {...}`), I would couple my code not just with a specific RDBMS but also with its constraint naming conventions. *Very, very bad*

**So, how do I provide a clear, specific error message to the user in case of a constraint violation while staying high-level?**